# Trying to unpack list of vertices into float

Tags: swift

I have this situation where I need to send some kind of OSC message, unfortunately the limitation is that the OSC list needs to be in this type of format: float, float, float .....

The original data is some bunch of Vertices data, vector_float3.

I am sure this is supposed to be simple, but I got a headache trying to "unpack" the list.

dataY is a list of vector_float3 values. I am not sure how to deal with this, supposedly there is a map, but that works on String only?

If I were to do it manually, I have to manually type every single item in the list:

```
    var mymessage:[Float] = []

    for data in dataY {
        mymessage.append(data.x)
        mymessage.append(data.y)
        mymessage.append(data.z)
    }


    let message = OSCMessage( OSCAddressPattern("/hello/osc"),
                              mymessage[0], mymessage[1], mymessage[2],
                              mymessage[3], mymessage[4], mymessage[5],
                              mymessage[6], mymessage[7], mymessage[8]
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vector_float3` is a *tuple,* and there is no simple conversion from
tuples to arrays in Swift, you have to access each tuple member
explicitly. You can achieve that a bit more compactly with

```
let myMessage = Array(dataY.map { [$0.x, $0.y, $0.z] }.joined())
```